# What "jet engine" is featured in this ad that Simone Giertz made for a phone?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification

Simone Giertz's video "Having Dinner With a Jet Engine/Leaf Blower" has a number of views of the turbine, on a cart, with a ducted fan attached.  [This side view](https://youtu.be/OhVwqdMbuiI) is the best view, in my opinion.
[image: Still from Simone's video showing the engine from the left side]
I put "jet engine" in quotes in the title because it doesn't seem like it's trying to produce thrust via exhaust, it looks like a turboshaft or turbine generator or maybe APU where the power is supposed to go into the output shaft and the hot exhaust just comes out the side, slow.  I'm guessing the ducted fan is an add-on but am not sure.

There's also a good shot of the control panel during start-up.  I haven't immediately noticed one that shows operating RPM.
[image: Still from Simone's video showing the control panel]

At least [one shot also shows a nameplate top-front on the compressor section](https://youtu.be/OhVwqdMbuiI?t=161) but it's not in focus and I can't make it out.

I feel the need to postfix this with:  I am not in any way affiliated with Simone Giertz or Google.

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows one gauge labeled "__T SEC RPM" (probably "hot section rpm"), and the one at the far left seems to also be something RPM, though it's too out of focus to be sure. Big gauge between them seems to be EGT - exhaust gas temperature.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was I didn't find any parts of the video that show the RPM gages reading other-than-zero as a clue to the operating RPM range (which could help in classifying the thing?), which doesn't appear to be marked on the gage.  The gage on the far left is "Gas Producer RPM" (it's more evident in other frames near the same time code).  I believe the RPM gage near the starter controls is "OUTPUT SEC RPM", also more evident from the adjacent few seconds of video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The engine seems quite obviously to be a Boeing T50 Turboshaft Engine variant, T50-BO-8A is a very, very close match, you can see pictures and info here:
[National Air and Space Museum: Boeing T50-BO-8A](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/boeing-t50-bo-8a-502-10vc-turboshaft-engine)

All major visible features are exactly the same, some minor parts are different, but may have been switched by current and/or previous owners.

Engine concept dates back to late 40's.

I did not add a picture here because of the copyright restriction posted on the National Air and Space Museum website.

Comment: Oh wow.  It's pretty striking how, with the clear nameplate shot on the NASM site showing where it is and the right size, I can now baaaaaaarely see the Boeing stamp on the nameplate in Simone's video.  I agree that this is most likely correct, or at least correct enough for my curiosity, so I'll wait the customary 24 hours and then accept.

Comment: @Erin Anne sometimes the brain needs a little help seeing stuff, since you basically can't see what you are not looking for :) I myself had no idea Boeing had ever made turbine engines...